# Why must I return a promise?

Tags: swift, promisekit

[Here](http://promisekit.org/introduction/) is the code...

```
login().then {

    // our login method wrapped an async task in a promise
    return API.fetchKittens()

}.then { fetchedKittens in

    // our API class wraps our API and returns promises
    // fetchKittens returned a promise that resolves with an array of kittens
    self.kittens = fetchedKittens
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}.catch { error in

    // any errors in any of the above promises land here
    UIAlertView(…).show()

}
```

See how the `then` method is not returning anything.

When I use `then` the compiler is saying I must return a promise. Why don't I have the choice not to?

The error goes away when I add a catch clause straight after. huh?

Comment: You might want to specify your types more precisely, as stated in the documentation http://promisekit.org/PromiseKit-2.0-Released/ (apparently the inference in inner closures is not perfect)

Comment: Answer here... https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/210. I added '-> Void' after the closure parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer [here](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/210).

I added `-> Void` after my closure parameter.

```
.then { fetchedKittens -> Void in }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.done{}` to finish promise chain, like this:

```
.done { fetchedKittens -> Void in }
```

`.then{}` with -> Void is not working anymore, because `.then{}` always need to return promise.

[Documentation](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#then--done)